# Highlighted Content Custom Query Filtering

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml, highlighted-content-web-part

I am trying to write a simple query to filter highlighted content and can't figure out the CAML to accomplish it.  The out of the box filter option is returning results in an odd order, and it needs to be sequential based on the GUID or a date column.  So far I have:

```
<Query>
  <Where>
    <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name="ColumnName" />
      <Value Type="Text">ColumnValue</Value>
    </Eq>
  </Where>
  <OrderBy>
    <FieldRef Name="DateColumn" Ascending="FALSE"/>
  </OrderBy>
</Query>
```

But nothing changes in the web part.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have to wrap your entire query with a  tag.

See the Microsoft Doc for more info with the screenshot under the Custom Query Section: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-the-Highlighted-content-web-part-e34199b0-ff1a-47fb-8f4d-dbcaed329efd

Comment: That worked!  I had to add the <View> element.